# Can this code result in infinite loop

Tags: c#

I am investigating some cases in my application. I have this code to read XML elements with the goal to skip those elements in which exception is triggered:

```
bool res = true;
// Start parsing the XML file
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath))
{
    while (res)
    {
        try
        {
            // Read 
            res = reader.Read();
            if (res == false)
                break;

            // Is this XML element?
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
            {
                // What is its name?
                if (reader.Name == "Test")
                {                        

                  //...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Exception - continue to reading other XML elements
            HelperMethods.AppendToLogFile("Method: TryRetrieveRestartReasons. " + terminalName + " " + "Filename: " + xmlFilePath + "Ex: " + ex.Message, LogType.Error);
            // HelperMethods.TryInsertParsingExceptionToDatabase(terminalName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlFilePath) + ".log", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is do you think above snippet can ever result in infinite loop?
Otherwise how would you proceed to write code where you skip those lines which generated exception in XML file

Comment: What is `reader` and what does `Read()` do? if it never equals false then yes there is a loop

Comment: @Sayse: It is XMLReader

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to loop until a stringreader / filereader / xmlreader etc is exhausted.

Comment: I designed this intentionally like this with the goal in mind if there is exception on some XML element to continue reading to other elements. But like I said as much as I have encountered if there is exception next time to do reader.Read() it returns false - so I would like to hear answer from someone who knows about this

Comment: @user300455 Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx. XmlReader will raise an the XmlException if it can't parse XML, so you can get infinite loop with invalid XML data.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: I said it can raise an Exception but after exception Reader.Read() ALWAYS returned false as much as I have checked. Do you understand my point ???

Comment: @user300455: `Read` can't return anything after thowing exception, because execution flow will be passed to the nearest `catch` block, who can catch exception, that has been thrown.

Comment: @Dennis: Why didn't you read my code carefully? After catch we still go to WHILE loop - and at that point (after the exception) Reader.Read typically returned FALSE when I tested

Comment: @user300455, yes, I did. You can't be sure that this behavior will occur in any case.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: OK so we agreed that *AFTER* Exception as much as I tested Reader.Read() returned false. But now you say that this might not *ALWAYS* be the case? Right? (otherwise if it where my code would work right?)

Comment: @user300455, Your code will work only if the XmlReader really reads at least one character from the input stream at any Read. In general, this assumption may be incorrect.

In addition, someone who will support your code will not know that you have tested all possible cases. It's better to write clear the code, not just only correct.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: Can you please describe me a scenario when my code above will result in infinite loop in simple terms? Answer by Dennis is not correct

Comment: F.e. simple lexical analyzer (that enough to split a XML-data into tokens) usually has a buffer for 1 character. It checks the character in this buffer and then switches itself state. If the new state is correct, it will read next character, but if the new state is "error", it's not obliged to read.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: I am sorry I don;t understand your sample - ut would be better to understand for me if you explained it in terms of reader.read returning true or false.. I think Dennis now understood my point after his edit in answer

Comment: There could be an infinite loop - not within this code block, but with either Somemethod(valueElement, "Testvalue"); or Dosmth(valueElement);

Hard to tell with so many dependent & nested functions.

Comment: @LocEngineer: I see I will check those - I doubt. The only candidate method for infinite loop was this XML.read() construct... check answer below

Answer (score 1):

Consider the scenario where `reader.Read()` reads successfully once, then throws exception for every time after that.

The first time the line `res = reader.Read()` gets called, `res` gets set to `true`. Then, each time afterwards `reader.Read()` throws an exception. The key part is that when it throws an exception nothing happens to `res`. It retains its value of `true`.

So, you catch the exception, `res` stays `true`, and the loop starts over. The `while` says "Yep, `res` is `true`. Keep going." Then, another exception is thrown before `res` can be set to anything else.

So, so long as it is `reader.Read()` throwing an exception and you have had at least one successful `Read()` call, then you will get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know answer from someone who is sure if reader.Read() will
>   always return false in my above code

It will not always return `false`.
Since [`XmlReader.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can throw exceptions (e.g., when XML is invalid), then here is a problem with `try-catch` and `reader.Read`.

If `Read` throws exception, then `t` never becomes `false`, and you'll get infinite loop. First line of the loop should be `while (reader.Read())`.

> the next time I called Reader.Read -- it returned FALSE

You can't be sure.
Even if this is true for now/for some XML samples, this is implementation detail. This behavior isn't documented. I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Dennis like I said if Read throws exception - the next time I called Reader.Read -- it returned FALSE. (Note: After exception still I will go to while loop - isn't it (because its designed like this) and then after exception typically when I tested reader.Read returned false)

Comment: @user300455: updated the answer. Relying on implementation details is a bad idea.

Comment: "the next time I called Reader.Read -- it returned FALSE
" -- I think this is the catch right? If this behaviour always happened then my code would be correct and not result in infinite loop right ??

Comment: and by the way how do you create solution which tries to continue to reading other XML elements if it encounters exception at some point (what my code was trying to achieve).

Comment: You're trying to design your code in the manner, that will be based on implementation details of 3rd-party code. Official docs says, that `Read` will throw exception. It doesn't say, that `Reader` will return `false` on subsequent iterations. This will work until implementation won't be changed. Is this critical for you? About reading the rest of XML: if XML structure is broken, you can't guarantee, that data you're trying to read will be valid. What's the point to continue reading int this case?

Comment: In my case it was needed to also read other XML elements... so what is your recommendation now? Code wise?

Comment: ps Dennis so you say it is not possible to create XML reader which continues to reading other XML elements in case there was exception ?? Thanks I wanted to ask a separate question about that

Comment: My point is either read valid XML completely, or throw invalid one away. I can't see any benefits from parsing invalid XML - this is rather complex task with unpredictable results.

Comment: So you recommend put `reader.Read` inside `while` condition? Which will exit if there is exception ...

Comment: @user300455: exactly.

Comment: just to save some time from asking additional quesiton - you think it makes no sense to ask a new question about how to continue reading other xml elements if there was exception?

Comment: @user300455: if this is a requirement, why no? But I'm afraid, that `XmlReader` won't help you here.