# Investigating weird case - thread dying?

Tags: c#

I had weird situation which i want to investigate. I will ask you specific questions and maybe you can help me figure out which of them are **realistic** so I can focus on investigating only those realistic causes?

In my app this happens inside timer:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Thread is running - exit timer
                if (isThreadRunning)
                {
                    HelperMethods.AppendToLogFile("Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer.", LogType.Information);
                    return;
                }

                // If we got this far, thread is not running, let's start it
                Thread myThread = new Thread(MainProcessingThread);
                myThread.IsBackground = true;
                isThreadRunning = true;
                myThread.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HelperMethods.AppendToLogFile("Exception inside timer. "+ex.Message, LogType.Error);

            }
        }
```

This is the main thread method:

```
 public void MainProcessingThread()
        {
            try
            {


                // Main method
                HelperMethods.TryProcessAll(threeDaysAgo.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                                                                  yesterday.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                                                                  Properties.Settings.Default.username,
                                                                  Properties.Settings.Default.password))


                // Flag which indicates thread was finished
                isThreadRunning = false; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                HelperMethods.AppendToLogFile("Exception inside MainProcessingThread: "+ex.Message, LogType.Error);
                isThreadRunning = false;

                return;
            }

            return;

        }
```

When I was looking at log files there were consecutive entries (for more than 36 hours) of: "Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer.". The application was alive; these messages came from inside timer.
This means that `isThreadRunning` was always true - even though in 36 hours the method `TryProcessAll` had to terminate - after which `isThreadRunning` would be set to false. But my log file just looked like this:

```
"Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer."
"Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer."
"Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer."
"Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer."....
```

My questions:

1. If there was Stack overflow exception inside `TryProcessAll` would this kill only the thread? Then why was the timer still alive when I came back?
2. If there was out of memory exception inside `TryProcessAll` why was not it logged? I log all exceptions inside `TryProcessAll`.
3. Could the OS kill my `MainProcessingThread`? In that case that could explain why when timer was called each time it checked `isThreadRunning` was true - so it was printing that message I said.

There are no other threads inside `TryProcessAll`

Comment: Looks like you might have an endless loop in 'TryProcessAll'. Can you show us what you are doing in there?

Comment: You should be declaring your `isThreadRunning` variable as `volatile` since it is being accessed on multiple threads. Not sure if you've done that or not.

Comment: @LocEngineer: Look at my other question for possible endless loop - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207466/can-this-code-result-in-infinite-loop. (I corrected that now btw). There is much going on in that function... it don't make sense probably to post all that code :(

Comment: @RonBeyer: There is just timer and one thread.

Comment: A timer runs on its own thread, so you do have multiple threads.

Comment: @RonBeyer: So you think that could be the cause of the problem? it is not volatile - isThreadRunning

Comment: Its a possibility, when you access a value on multiple threads the processor may cache the value, if you don't declare it as volatile the value will be read from the cache instead of its memory location.

Comment: @RonBeyer: so it should be `public static volatile bool isThreadRunning`? This is field of the main form. ? And it didn't change for 36 hours? it was cached?

Comment: Yes, and computers have no concept of time, it'll cache it until the sun crashes into the earth if it can. I'm curious why you are using static fields in an instance of a form though?

Comment: @RonBeyer: That is good point about static/form instance I am a bit new to C# that is why. So you say I should change it to: `public static volatile bool isThreadRunning` and it won't damage anything?

Comment: It won't damage anything, and I'd drop the `static` part too. I'm not 100% sure this is the problem but its the proper way to handle that (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx ).

Comment: @RonBeyer: Ok let's see also other opinions. I hope people will post other opinions too

Comment: Another thing you want to do is to put the `isThreadRunning = false;` inside a `finally` block in the `MainProcessingThread`, there is a case where if the `HelperMethods.AppendToLogFile` throws an exception the flag will never get reset. Using it in a `finally` ensures it is set no matter what.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Ron `AppendToLogFile`  never throws, but you were right.

Comment: You might not throw, but I'm sure there is a case where something inside the method can throw. Any file operation can raise an exception for example.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I mean whole body of `AppendToLogFile` file is located inside `try/catch`

Answer (score 0):

Ahahahahahaha!

I think we are all thinking too complicated here!
Look what you are doing:

```
if (isThreadRunning)
                {
                    HelperMethods.AppendToLogFile("Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer.", LogType.Information);
                    return;
                }

                // If we got this far, thread is not running, let's start it
                Thread myThread = new Thread(MainProcessingThread);
                myThread.IsBackground = true;
                isThreadRunning = true;
                myThread.Start();
```

Now guess what happens once the thread finishes?
==>You start it over again. As long as no errors happen, you  will ALWAYS get that exact line:

```
Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer.
```

So, no, nothing weird is happening. You just don't check whether the thread has run once and finished or not yet run at all!

It runs, finishes, gets started over again...

THERE's your infinite loop!

Comment: No. Inside `TryProcessAll` I log some sentence. Like: "Started doing this". And after that there are only such sentences in my log file: "Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer.", "Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer.", "Inside timer. Thread didn't finish yet so we quit the timer.", ... Consecutively with no messages in between. And  "Started doing this". is typically follwed by "Finished doing this" log entry inside `TryProcessAll` method - and that finished doing this is never shown in log file

Comment: In that case... There were only log entries in catch() visible from the code you provided. Pity, It's usually the simplest things. It's back to the other code then. You sure as hell have created yourself a nice labyrinth here.

Comment: "There were only log entries in catch() visible from the code you provided" - not sure what you mean. It is either problem from XMLRead like in my second question. Or the variable should be volatile like discussed above. Or NR1 and NR2 cases like mentioned in my above question. " You sure as hell have created yourself a nice labyrinth here." - did I? Yes, but like I said I am investigating realistic cases now

Comment: I am always sceptical about reducing the possible cause to two things when there are still several unknown further things happening that might or might not cause the error.
See the "goto fail" bug...

Comment: if volatile dont help and my other so question which seem reasonable, then only 1,2,3 remains as listed in my question above

Answer (score -1):

Generally, after an OutOfMemoryException and a SatckOverflowException your program is in a rather unstable let's say *exceptional* state.

You should not do much more than exiting after such an exception.

It is not guaranteed that any operation like writing a log will proceed successfully. (because it does not get any more memory for example)

---

**Edit: Clearification**

If a thread allocates memory, the underlying OS is called with the request to enlarge the process' memory. If the OS cannot honour this request a OutOfMemoryException is thrown. From this point on all requests for more memory will fail. If the thread runs into another memory allocation request (any string operation, any new) this operation will fail with another OutOfMemoryException.

This means, after a OutOfMemoryException only extremely simple code, guaranteed to not allocate additional memory can execute.

A call to a logger mechanism is certainly not simple enough.

Comment: my question was if there was stack overflow exception inside thread (MainProcessingThread) - why was my application still alive? that is what I asked

Comment: this doesn't answer my quesion; please look at the specific questiond more carefuly

Comment: I tried to answer: " why was not it logged?" (Number 2 of your very specific questions)

Comment: If the logger needs one more byte of memory it can't do its work after memory was exhausted.

Comment: So you mean if there was out of memory exception or stack overflow exception inside that thread - then the timer weren't meant to be running??

Comment: Complicated code inside the **same** thread is unlikely to succeed

Comment: So you say out of memory exception is unlikely?

Comment: No, that is not what I say.